# In Java, how to write to a file from input stream? I am getting IOException: Pipe closed

Tags: java, file, inputstream, ioutils

I created a file and writing an input stream to it but I am getting this exception with just this info `IOException: Pipe closed.`

Here is my code:

```
File outputFile = new File(filePath);

try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream); // exception here
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new FileWritingException("Exception while writing file::" + e.getMessage());
}
```

I also tried adding the following but still the same error. Only empty file gets created in that output location.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(outputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new FileWritingException("Exception while writing file::" + e);
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
}
```

FYI, I am getting input stream from implementing sftp java lib jsch as

```
ChannelSftp channelSftp = setupJsch();
InputStream stream = channelSftp.get(<pathtoFileInExternalFtPLocation>);
```

```
public ChannelSftp setupJsch() throws JSchException {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    jsch.setKnownHosts("known-hosts-path");

    Session jschSession = jsch.getSession(USERNAME, HOST, PORT);
    jschSession.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    jschSession.setProxy(new ProxyHTTP(SFTP_PROXY_HOST, SFTP_PROXY_PORT));
    Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put(STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING_KEY, STRICT_HOST_KEY_CHECKING_VAL);
    jschSession.setConfig(config);
    jschSession.connect();
    return (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel(AMLEFileConstants.SFTP);
  }
```

Jsch: https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html

Comment: check whether your inputstream is valid or not

Comment: +1 to @gvmani's suggestion. It could be that your FTP connection is getting closed before it's read out. Perhaps try printing a line to stdout

Comment: My guess is that you are closing the socket(?) before calling method `copy`. Do you have a stack trace for the `IOException`?

Comment: When you wrap an exception, always pass the original exception as the cause of the wrapping exception. That way you keep the full stack trace.

Comment: Please provide the entire stack trace. I don't see how you can get this exception writing to a file. What was the filename?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who replied in comments. Based on your pointers, I just tried another overloading of this get call provided by this API as `void get(<pathtoFileInExternalFtPLocation>, OutputStream <destLocation>)` that drops output stream in destLocation directly into the dest file instead of dealing with Input Stream as a return type. And that worked.

https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#get-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-